# True or false? $(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$ is a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> True or false? $(\mathbb{Z} \setminus \left\{0\right\}, \cdot)$ is a
>   group

I need to know this because it's from an old exam and it might be asked in my exam, or a task like that.

I'm not entirely sure but I would say that the statement is false. The associative property will work, there will be an identity element too. But we will fail when we are looking for inverse elements as these would require rational numbers.

(So even if we had something like $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$, it wouldn't be a group still.)

---

I hope I did it alright?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. $2$ has no inverse, for instance.

Comment: A downvote? I'm fairly sure I'm not wrong.